# Why is FORCE JOIN option slowing down query and forcing execution plan to sort prior to joining tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm linking **Orders** data with the **Results** data for those orders. Here's the SQL query for joining and selecting the

```
; with orders as (
    select o.*, otr.*, oo.*
    from Order o
    inner join OrderTransitionRecord otr
        on otr.Order_oid = o.ObjectID
    inner join OccurrenceOrder oo
        on oo.Order_oid = o.ObjectID
), results as (
    select ir.*, irsi.*
    from InvestigationResult ir
    left outer join InvestigationResultSuppInfo irsi
        on irsi.ObjectID = ir.ResultSuppInfo_oid
), anchor as (
    select orders.*, results.*
    from orders
    inner join results
        on results.Occurrence_oid = orders.OO_oid
        and results.IR_Patient_oid = orders.O_Patient_oid
        and results.IR_PatientVisit_oid = orders.O_PatientVisit_oid
)
select top 100000 *
from anchor
```

This takes ~35 seconds and follows [this execution plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okgm2wvpwka3hwj/original.sqlplan?dl=0). If you look at the execution plan, you'll see that it first joins (`OccurrenceOrder`, `OrderTransitionRecord`) with `InvestigationResult`...and then joins that result with `Order`. My question is why doesn't it first join all three tables (`Order`, `OccurrenceOrder`, `OrderTransitionRecord`) that are inside the `orders` CTE prior to joining with the tables (`InvestigationResult`, `InvestigationResultSuppInfo`) that are in the `results` CTE?

I tried forcing the order of the joins by adding the `OPTION(FORCE JOIN)` option at the end of the select query. However, it slowed the query down  by a factor of 2 (~75 seconds). Here's the [execution plan for when I force the join order](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kljm99rybqxe2aq/forced%20join%20order.sqlplan?dl=0). If you take a look at it, you'll see that the join order is forced correctly, but it has to sort the results of clustered index scans on all 3 Order tables before joining them. Why does it need to do that?

What can I do to speed up my query? I've already made sure that the tables have indices for all the columns that are needed in all the joins. Any and all help would be much appreciated. Thanks

### Original

[image]

### Force Order

[image]

Comment: `select top 100000 * from anchor` won't give you deterministic results. What is the query supposed to be doing? Also table definitions including indexes?

Comment: I assume the CTE is "collapsed" by the optimizer (SQL-Server's optimizer simplifies CTEs this way - in difference with Postgres where CTEs are an optimization barrier).

Comment: And the way you have written your query, the columns involved in the last join `on results.Occurrence_oid = orders.OO_oid and results.IR_Patient_oid = orders.O_Patient_oid and results.IR_PatientVisit_oid = orders.O_PatientVisit_oid`, we have no idea which tables belong to, so I don't know how anyone can help you. Try rewriting the query without CTEs , with all the tables in one `FROM` clause and edit the question.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith! Removing the `top 10000 *` sped up the forced join order query.

Comment: That is good to know, @ypercube. Sorry, I was hesitant to post the entire table definitions without first getting permission from my boss. The `O_, OO_, IR_` correspond to the aliased tables in the CTEs, but I admit that it was unclear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MartinSmith: How did you convert the sqlplan files to images so that you could upload them? Also what did you use to highlight/bolden parts of the plan?

Comment: @Synergist - These are just screen shots from [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) TBH i wasn't expecting removing the `TOP` to improve things. Removing the [row goal](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx) must have altered things in a lucky way.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after heeding advice from the comments, I removed the `top 10000 *` from the select statement. After doing so, forcing the join order actually sped up the query as intended. It took 48 seconds (vs. 60 sec).

Here's the [original execution plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okgm2wvpwka3hwj/original.sqlplan?dl=0).

And here's the [forced join execution plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kljm99rybqxe2aq/forced%20join%20order.sqlplan?dl=0).